# Theorem 3.2 Rudin -- How is 0 concluded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

- *I'm having trouble understanding why the arbitrariness of $\epsilon$ allows us to conclude that $d(p,p')<0$. It seems we could likely
  conclude a value such as $\frac {\epsilon}{100}$ couldn't we?? The
  other idea that would normally work is the limit (as $n$ approaches
  $\infty$, $p$ approaches $p'$) but that would mean we are further in
  another sequence which would have same problem Thanks in advance*

$\ $ 
$\ $ 
$\ $

Definition of Convergence

> A sequence $\{ p_n \}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to converge if there us a point $p \in X$ with the following property: For every $ \epsilon>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies distance function $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon.$

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had solved a similar problem recently. Try proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial thing to note here is that $p, p'$ are fixed points in $X$ (ie they don't depend on $n$) and hence $d(p, p') $ is non-negative specific real number and let's denote this specific non-negative number by $A$. It should now be clear that in the inequality $A<\epsilon$ the number $A$ is fixed and $\epsilon$ is arbitrary. Since $A$ is fixed it can not be chosen to be something like $\epsilon/100$. The implication $$\forall \epsilon>0,0\leq A<\epsilon\implies A=0$$ is just a fancy way (like the legalese) to mean the following obvious/trivial fact:

> **The** only non-negative real number less than **any/every** positive real number is $0$.

To convince yourself that the above is trivial understand that the statement remains true even if word "real" is replaced by "rational" and this property of rationals is an immediate consequence of the following

> Given any positive rational number we can find a smaller positive rational number.

And the above follows from the even more obvious fact

> Given any natural number we can find a greater one, namely it's successor.

It is a trademark of authors like Rudin who convert such trivialities into seemingly difficult results via excessive use of symbolism in the name of "unambiguous / precise writing".

If these statements do not look trivial then it time to revisit the way inequalities work in these number systems.

Answer (score 4):

The moral is that the only $x\ge 0$ satisfying $x< \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ is $0$. For, suppose that $x\ne 0$, then $x=\delta>0$. Choose $\epsilon = \frac{\delta}{2}$. Then $x\not< \epsilon$, contrary to assumption.

Because $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the statement is true for all $\epsilon>0$, and thus we are done.

Comment: So the idea being that if choose a value of $x \neq 0$ then we can find an $\epsilon$ less than it? And that we want to settle on a value of $x$ so that $x < \epsilon$ will always hold and $0$ can be the only value?? And thanks!

Comment: That’s exactly the idea.

Comment: Can make it even simpler.  Let $\epsilon = x > 0$.  Then $x < \epsilon = x$.  So $x < x$.  Which... is not possible.

Comment: It's not, smaller than all positive numbers except itself.  It's smaller than all positive numbers including itself and any positive numbers smaller than itself.  Well no positive number is smaller than itself.  ANd no positive number can be smaller than other numbers that are small than itself (and all positive numbers have numbers smaller than itself)... we have to conclude $x$ can not be positive.  But $x \ge 0$ means $x$ can not be negative.  There's only one option left...

Answer (score 1):

$d(p,p') \ge 0$.

Case 1:  $d(p,p') > 0$.

Let $\epsilon = d(p,p') > 0$.  Then $d(p,p') < \epsilon = d(p,p')$.  That is a contradiction.

Case 2:  $d(p,p') = 0$.

Then..... $d(p,p') = 0$.....